# I am unable to boot into a fresh insallation of 18.04 with the error "Missing boot loader", what do I do?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

After creating a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04, I booted the system with the error message "Missing boot loader". No other information is listed. I have attempted to use utilities to repair GRUB, however, they have not been successful. When I check the boot menu, I only am able to see my HDD (which is the main drive). I don't know if the hardware could be affecting this, however, it is an older Lenovo Q180 with 4gb of RAM.

Note: This is not dual-booting and all partitions were removed with GParted before I began the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a UEFI installation of Ubuntu and that your machine also boots in UEFI and not in legacy mode.